# Inicialização automática

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

Tenho um programa em Python e preciso que ele inicie automaticamente junto com o Windows, não consegui encontrar nenhum material relacionado a isso na internet.

Comment: Quais versões do Windows? Você tem como garantir que o Python 3 vai estar instalado nas máquinas onde esse programa vai auto-inicializar?

Comment: Windows 7, no caso, o programa será ".exe", logo, não precisaria do interpretador instalado.

Comment: a palavra Inicialização não existe

Comment: http://www.dicio.com.br/inicializacao/ Sério?

Answer (score 1):

1. Tecle Win+R para abrir o menu “Executar…”;
2. Digite “shell:Startup” pra abrir a pasta “Inicializar”.

Qualquer programa cujo atalho você arraste pra essa pasta vai ser executado quando o Windows inicializar.

(Se você precisar parâmetros pela linha de comando para o programa, você vai precisar criar um arquivo `.bat` que o faça.)

Comment: Preciso que o próprio Python faça isso, tem como?

Comment: Aparentemente `os.environ['CSIDL_STARTUP']` é o diretório certo; você pode fazer o seu programa se copiar pra lá e.g. `shutil.copyfile(sys.argv[0], os.path.join(os.environ['CSIDL_STARTUP'], os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))`

Comment: Acho que consegui tirar uma base, obrigado pela ajuda ctgPi.

Answer (score 1):

Clique em **Menu Iniciar** > **Todos os programas** > **Inicializar**

Em inglês: **Start Menu** > **All programas** > **Startup**

Dentro da pasta inicializar, coloque o atalho do seu arquivo **.bat** que vai abrir o seu programa python ao inicilizar o Windows.

Para criar o arquivo **.bat** você pode abrir o bloco de notas e digitar isso:

```
start Python caminho
```

No lugar de caminho você coloca onde está seu arquivo em python **.py**. Se o arquivo estiver na mesma pasta que o arquivo **.bat** apenas coloque o nome do arquivo. Exemplo:

```
teste.py
```

Senão, você coloca o caminho inteiro, exemplo:

```
start Python C:/Users/User/Desktop/teste.py
```

Na hora de salvar como, não se esqueça de salvar como arquivo **.bat**: `start.bat` por exemplo. [Aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-a-arquivos-bat-e-programacao-em-lotes/24800) está explicando um pouco sobre arquivos **.bat** caso precise.

Caso não funcione, confira se o [Python está no caminho do sistema](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path).